# jmeter script getting slower and slower

Tags: groovy, jmeter

[image]

[image]

I have the simple script which generate three parameters, and in jmeter it shows it becomes slower and slower... I don't know why, is there any ways to optimize it?

The red line shows the script's changing trend.

Comment: Have you tried with different script languages?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't inline JMeter functions into Groovy scripts, either use "Parameters" instead or even better go for [RandomStringUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) like:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils

   vars.put("uid", RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20))
   vars.put("cpOrderId",RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(30))
   vars.put("sessionId",RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(16))

   log.info("uid: " + vars.get("uid"))
   log.info("cpOrderId: " + vars.get("cpOrderId"))
   log.info("sessionId: " + vars.get("sessionId"))
   ```

   [image: JMeter Groovy Random String]
2. Make sure you are following [JMeter best practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure), to wit:

   - run your test in non-GUI mode
   - amend JVM Heap settings to be around 80% of total available physical RAM
   - amend default GC options

Comment: Yeah I tried this later, but it still consumes a lot of time.